# Change navigation bar background for single view in iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uinavigationbar

To set the navigation bar background the the entire application I have this code in app delegate:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

However I want to have a different background for the initial view, actually its the same but has a custom font and logo init. I tried settings this:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar-start.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

But this applied the change for the entire application. I am developing for ios7. **How can I set a different background just for the initial view?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The navigationbar is common across all views in a navigation controller. So if you want to apply an image only for a single view, you can include the second code fragment in `viewWillAppear` of the concerned viewcontroller, and reset the image to the original one in `viewWillDisappear`

Comment: thank you that worked, however with a little problem, when you swipe to navigate back instead of clicking the back button, the image instantly appears instead of fading in.

Comment: How should it ideally work? In case of color I think iOS automatically animates between the two.